# How to access microsoft teams with C#, execute teams commands and get result data with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to figure out how to access MS Teams or Skype commands, which are listed here, [Teams commands link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/?view=teams-ps) from within c#. Is there any way this can be done?

I can execute the commands from powershell, by importing the teams or skype module, but I want to execute the commands from within c# instead and retrieve the result data in order to process it afterwards. Is there any documentation on the subject? Or maybe somebody has done this.

EDIT: For example, this is how I would run the command "Get-CsOnlineVoiceRoute" in powershell. Its a pseudocode

```
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector

$sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -SessionOption (some options)
Import-PSSession #sfbSession -AllowClobber

Get-CsOnlineVoiceRoute
```

In the answers bellow, the guys suggest that I can use the Microsoft Graph API to do this. But can somebody show me an example call. Maybe with the command im using. How can I get the same results using the API? Or is there any documentation about what ps command relates to what api calls?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api). The Microsoft Graph API is a RESTful API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources (e.g. even Teams). The `MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell` PowerShell module is simply a convenient wrapper making API calls on your behalf for you. Since C# can also make RESTful API calls, I recommend accessing the API directly for the most seamless user experience.

Accessing and configuring Microsoft Graph API is beyond the scope of SO, and I recommend going over their [Graph Quick Start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) page to go over some basic code samples to get you started. If you can do this type of request:

```
{HTTP method} https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{resource}?{query-parameters}
```

Then you are all set up to access the API. The specific API section/resource you are interested in is the [Microsoft Graph Teams API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). The Microsoft documentation has more info on what you might be trying to achieve.

Other things to keep in mind is, if you can't seem to do something, that while `v1.0` of the API is "Production" live, the `beta` version has many more additional resources available and may have a feature you need. (esp. when dealing with Azure Active Directory, there are certain things that can only be done with the `beta` version of the API). I find the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to be extremely helpful in finding out exactly what type of requests I need to make before I start coding.

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of this API. I've slightly modified my question in order to show exactly what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) call to call teams commands. Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/csharp-teams-sample-graph)?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT , thanks for replying, i've slightly modified my question in order to show  exactly what im trying to do. I'm looking at your examples in github, but can you better point me if I wanted to specifically get results like the ones in this command "Get-CsOnlineVoiceRoute" what call would I have to do. (I'm still a junior dev, some of the stuff is confusing me ;x )

Comment: Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0), Check if that helps.